# Форматирование текста JS (RegExp)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Я тут практикуюсь в изучении JavaScript и столкнулся с одной ситуацией: Мне для нормального функционирования нужно число (к примеру 32) перевести в формат "0032".
В Ruby помню достаточно было сделать так:
`a = sprintf("%04d", 32) #=> "0032"`
Мне было бы интересно, как такое можно сделать без нагромождения условиями небольшой части кода.

Comment: исходя из примера по коду из Ruby "%04d" сначала создает строку "0000" а потом заменяет последние знаки на число. sprintf("%04d", 7) #=> "0007", sprintf("%04d", 32) #=> "0032",  sprintf("%04d", 445) #=> "0445", sprintf("%04d", 1337) #=> "1337"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Я не готов подсказать решения.
Предлогаю посмотреть в сторону [https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ данный Алексеем в комментарии к вопросу решил мою задачу.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart.
Даже когда я работал не в Мозиле а в Опере.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function toFourDigits( num ){
  if( isNaN( num ) || !isFinite( num ) ){ return '"' + num + '" is not a number'; }
  return ("0000" + num).slice(-4); 
}

console.log( toFourDigits(7) );
console.log( toFourDigits(32) );
console.log( toFourDigits(510) );
console.log( toFourDigits(4510) );

console.log( toFourDigits( "Ошибка" ) );
console.log( toFourDigits( 1/0 ) );
```